# Why does I get SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE error when requesting a website?

Tags: python, urllib, urllib2

My code is below:

```
    import urllib.request
    import urllib.parse
    from lxml import etree

    HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'}
    url = url + urllib.parse.quote(word)
    print('search: ', word)
    req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=HEADERS, method='GET')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    text = response.read().decode('utf-8')
```

This works fine, but after about 400 requests, I got this error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1076)>
```

What might be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The connection is being rejected during the TLS handshake for some reason. It could just be something transient (and a retry would work) or it may be due to a mismatch due to TLS protocol versions or ciphers. Or it could also be for other reasons that aren't immediately obvious, like a block list, or a broken server etc.

Adding some detection to your code that retries a few times then skips is probably a good general approach. Something like:

```
for i in range(0,3):
    try:
        # CONNECT
    except:
        continue
    break
```

If you want to understand exactly why this particular URL is failing, the easiest solution is to download a copy of [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and see what is happening on the wire. There will likely be a TLS error, and possibly an alert code and message that gives more information.

Comment: Can you please use my code above to add code for retries and then skips? I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: I could, but part of the coding experience is making mistakes and then learning from them: you'd be robbing yourself of the learning experience ;) Take a look at this page which describes how to catch and handle thrown errors, then use the approach to deal with the failure in urllib. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp

Comment: I know how to use simple try...except block, but how to try 3 times of the same request? And how to pause for a few seconds?

Comment: OK。That's the way to retry the request. I will try.

Comment: Why do you need "while True"? For each retry, you do the connection; if successul, break, then why do another retry? if failed, continue? I don't quite understand the logic.

Comment: Ah, cut and paste error. You just need the ```for```. I've updated the answer. Again. ;)

Comment: Should we typically sleep for a few seconds in the except block? In case some website doesn't want you to send request fast.

Comment: That also works. Just include time and then sleep for a second within the ```except:```